# Legal Minimum Third Party Liability Insurance for Rental Car - USA

Tags: car-rentals, insurance

What is the legal minimum third party liability insurance for rental car for every US state?

Comment: Asking for every US state is IMHO too broad.

Comment: @JoErNanO and yet answerable...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I won't post the entire table, but this site should get you on your way: https://www.nerdwallet.com/blog/insurance/car-insurance/

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. Links are prone to 404 oblivion.

Comment: @JoErNanO links may indeed be prone to 404 issues, but this sort of information tends to relatively rapidly get out of date anyway, so its a toss up - link to a site that has motivation to keep its info up to date, or out of date info in the answer itself...

Comment: I invited you to [chat.](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/591/you-are-here)